# Wait for popen3 process to finish?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process, popen

I have a Rails application that uses `Open3.popen3`. It works fine but sometimes the application will go on without waiting for the process to finish.

Here is what the function I am using `Open3.popen3` in looks like (essentially it runs a `cat` function):

```
def cat_func(var)
  ## some stuff happens 
  exit = 0
  Open3.popen3(" #{cat_command}"){|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    pid = wait_thr.pid 
    error = std err.gets
    exit = wait_thr.value
  }
  #HERE IS TRYING TO INTERCEPT ERRORS:
  if error.match(/^cat:/)
    ### Do something
  end
  call_next_function
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When does it work, when doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess: maybe you have to also consume the *stdout*, so maybe adding a line like

```
def cat_func(var)
  exit = 0
  Open3.popen3(" #{cat_command}") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    pid   = wait_thr.pid 
    stdout.gets
    error = stderr.gets
    exit  = wait_thr.value
  end

  # more stuff...
end
```

fixes the problem?

Comment: ruby 1.8 does not have the fourth argument so I had to leave out all references to wait_thr;  Also, I had to close stdin and the run gets on stdout, and It seems to work.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I unfortunately could not test the code, so sorry for all errors in the piece above. I just remembered running into a similar issue with the open4 gem... Maybe you can post the correct code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here is my final solution:

```
Open3.popen3(command) do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  stdin.puts instructions
  stdin.close  # make sure the subprocess is done
  stdout.gets  # and read all output - EOF means the process has completed.
  stderr.gets
end
```